# CurrentUser function in Reports?

Tags: civireport, activities, dashboard

I'm wondering if it is possible for the "Assignee Name" field in a report to have a Current User function. My goal is to create 1 report for the CiviCRM Dashboard where users can see all the activities assigned to them without creating a filter for each person.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite what you're looking for but if you install the Extended Reports extension then you can do:

1. Go to Administer - CiviReport - Create Report from Template.
2. Pick extended report - activities.
3. Pick some columns for the activity.
4. On the Display Options tab, check the box to display as a tab on the contact record, and for the box below that choose assignee.
5. Click refresh results.
6. From the actions dropdown choose Create Report.

Then on any given contact they'll have a tab that shows their assigned activities.

Comment: I can make that work!